# Is there any restriction for the app in China region?

Tags: huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

An app is not displaying while searching in Huawei app gallery.

Is there any restriction for the app in China region?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not `programming`/`development` related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any restriction, but if you want to publish on China region , you need to modify your module UI content.
Please change [Bank Country] to [Bank Country/ Regions], and rule out such problems under other modules or other languages. We found in the Beneficiary module Bank Country it should be Bank Country/Regions:

[add_beneficiary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIDRN.png)

Please refer below link for more details:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30208#h1-5-language-issues